# Using CSS grid to replicate Mondrian painting

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I was following along with this youtube tutorial to make a Responsive Mondrian painting with CSS Grid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNtJ5p3h2A4&list=PLbSquHt1VCf1x_-1ytlVMT0AMwADlWtc1&index=3

So I have `img` tags to represent each cell. And put them into a `ul`

And according to the video basically all the css I need to write to make it look like the Mondrian painting is

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/01.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/02.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/03.jpg" alt="yellow" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/04.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/05.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/06.jpg" alt="red" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/07.jpg" alt="yellow" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/08.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/09.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/10.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/11.jpg" alt="black" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/12.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/13.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/14.jpg" alt="yellow" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/15.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/16.jpg" alt="blue" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/17.jpg" alt="red" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/18.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/19.jpg" alt="black" /></li>
    <li><img src="media/01-011/20.jpg" alt="white" /></li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

However the outcome is, every grid cell seems not aware of the image it contains and the image just spills out of the cell. I've attached a screenshot to show you what I mean. 
[image]

Here is the link to a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-pike-ocgr2?file=/index.html

I hope someone can explain to me on a fundamental level as to why is it that all the images spill out of the its cell

Comment: max-width:100% to the image ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it it doesn't work

Comment: There's a lot missing in your code from that tutorial bunch of little tricks to fix the layout, like having a dark background to hide spots where no img can fit `clip-path` to cut out the  borders on the outside placing each img where it should etc... [revised demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-forest-ybhqs)

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks for the revision but I don't think she ever mentioned ` clip-path` in that tutorial I linked in my question. I know there is something lacking in my code in order to make a full Mondrian painting. But since I'm learning CSS grid, I really want to understand on a fundamental level that why is it that my images all spill out of the grid cell, and the grid cell doesn't wrap the images properly and flow to the next row as intended.

Comment: The items didn't wrap because the minim width you specified is way to small they just didn't hit it yet, 20 pics times `20px` is 400px you need to be at lestt than `400px` wide for them to start wrapping, the images are spilling out because they're too wide than their grid area `max-width:100%;` should fix that.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thanks for the reply. what does `clip-path` do in this case? also is it necessary to set images to be `display: block;`?

Comment: Nop `clip-path` is merely used to cut the borders of `<li>` element on the outer edge. it's just a quick dirty fix to remove all the outer borders in one go instead of disabling each one alone.

Answer (score -1):

Original .scss for this painting:

```
     * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }  
        html {
          font-family: 'Futura W01', helvetica, san-serif;
          line-height: 1.3;
          font-size: 100%;
          color: #3C3C3B;
          font-weight: 300;
          background: white;
        }
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
        img {
          display: block;
        }
        ul, li {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
        }
        a {
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Index Page
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .index {
          main {
            margin: 3rem;
          }
          ul {
            margin: 2rem auto;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
          }
          li {
            max-width: 300px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
          }
          img {
            width: 100%;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
          }
          .original img {
            margin-top: 10px;
          }
          a {
            display: block;
          }
          @supports (display: grid) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
              grid-gap: 2rem;
              width: auto;
            }
            li {
              width: auto;
              margin: 0;
            }
          }
        }
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Deconstructed Mondrian
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .A {
          main {
            width: 70%;
            margin: 10vw auto;
          }
          img {
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
            border: 6px solid black;
          }  
          li {
            margin: 1em 0;
          }
        }
        
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // All the Assembled Mondrians
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .B, .C, .D, .E {
          img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
          }
          ul {
            background: #1C1B1B;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10px 6px, calc(100% - 7px) 6px, calc(100% - 7px) calc(100% - 6px), 10px calc(100% - 6px));
            clip-path: polygon(10px 6px, calc(100% - 7px) 6px, calc(100% - 7px) calc(100% - 6px), 10px calc(100% - 6px));
          }
          li {
            border: 6px solid black;
          }
        }
        
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Fluid Mondrian
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .B {
          margin: -8px -8px -8px -10px;
          overflow: hidden;
          ul {  /* autoprefixer: off */
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr) 1.2fr 1.2fr 0.5fr;
            grid-template-rows: 11vw repeat(5, 13vw) 11vw 6.5vw 6.5vw;
          }
        }
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Responsive Mondrian
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .C {  
          margin: 0 100px;
          main {
            margin: 4vw auto;
          }
          main {
            max-width: 940px;
          }
          ul {  /* autoprefixer: off */
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: 80px;
            grid-auto-flow: dense; 
          }
          @media (min-width: 940px) {
            main {
        
            }
          }
        }
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Responsive Mondrian, keeping aspect ratio
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .D {
          main {
            width:80%;
            margin: 4vw auto;
          }
          ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-flow: dense; 
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, calc(80vw/1));
            grid-template-rows: repeat(1, calc(80vw/1)); 
            max-width: 880px;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }
          @media (min-width: 300px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(2, calc(80vw/2));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(2, calc(80vw/2)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 400px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(80vw/3));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(3, calc(80vw/3)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 500px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(80vw/4));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(4, calc(80vw/4)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 600px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(5, calc(80vw/5));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(5, calc(80vw/5)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 700px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(6, calc(80vw/6));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(6, calc(80vw/6)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 800px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(7, calc(80vw/7));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(7, calc(80vw/7)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 900px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(8, calc(80vw/8));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(8, calc(80vw/8)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 1000px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(9, calc(80vw/9));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(9, calc(80vw/9)); 
            }
          }
          @media (min-width: 1100px) {
            ul { /* autoprefixer: off */
              grid-template-columns: repeat(9, calc(880px/9));
              grid-template-rows: repeat(9, calc(880px/9)); 
            }
          }
        }
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Responsive Diamond Mondrian
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .E {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          height: 100vh;
          main {
            width: calc(90vw - 12px);
            margin: 10px auto;
            clip-path: polygon(50% 2%, 98% 50%, 50% 98%, 2% 50%);
          }
          ul {  /* autoprefixer: off */
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: 80px;
            grid-auto-flow: dense; 
            height: calc(90vw + 12px);
            width: calc(90vw + 12px);
            margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
          }
          @media (min-width: 880px) {
            main, ul {
              width: 800px;
              height: 800px;
            }
          }
        }
        
        
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        // Size the Blocks in all the variations
        // ------------------------------------------------------------
        
        .block-sizes {
          li:nth-child(1) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(2) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 3;
          }
          li:nth-child(3) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(4) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 6;
          }
          li:nth-child(5) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(6) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 4;
            grid-row: span 4;
          }
          li:nth-child(7) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(8) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 3;
          }
          li:nth-child(9) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(10) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(11) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(12) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(13) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(14) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 3;
          }
          li:nth-child(15) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(16) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 2;
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(17) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-row: span 3;
          }
          li:nth-child(18) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
            grid-row: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(19) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 2;
          }
          li:nth-child(20) { /* autoprefixer: off */
            grid-column: span 4;
          }
        }
```